# Thurston geometries in dimension 4

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, 4-manifolds

In the sense of W. Thurston [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture#The_eight_Thurston_geometries), there is 3 geometries in dimension 2  and there is 8 geometries in dimension 3.

Question: **How many different geometries (in the sense of Thurston) do we have in dimension 4 ?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The 4-dimensional geometries were classified in the unpublished thesis of Filipkiewicz, which is available [here](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/954/).

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you for the reference! Just for the future reader: the total classification is summarized in pages 129-131. The answer is: There is 19 geometries in dimension 4!

Comment: At the bottom of page (ii) it says "there is a countable infinite of inequivalent such geometries."

Comment: You are right Peter! I need to find a good formulation, it is like there is 19 geometries, and one of them is parametrized by natural numbers.